How can i do to wait for signal forever?
How can i do to wait for signal forever?
IPAddress serverAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.66");
const int serverPort = 7777;
string filename = "test.txt";

using var client = new TcpClient(serverAddress.ToString(), serverPort);
using var stream = client.GetStream();

byte[] buf = new byte[65536];
await ReadBytes(sizeof(long));
long remainingLength = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverter.ToInt64(buf, 0));

using var file = File.Create(filename);
while (remainingLength > 0)
{
    int lengthToRead = (int)Math.Min(remainingLength, buf.Length);
    await ReadBytes(lengthToRead);
    await file.WriteAsync(buf, 0, lengthToRead);
    remainingLength -= lengthToRead;
}

async Task ReadBytes(int howmuch)
{
    int readPos = 0;
    while (readPos < howmuch)
    {
        var actuallyRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buf, readPos, howmuch - readPos);
        if (actuallyRead == 0)
            throw new EndOfStreamException();
        readPos += actuallyRead;
    }
}

I need to infinite wait for signal while waiting for file from server port
Await is waiting for 20 seconds, then it kills programm

You might want to check this answer in Russian Stack Overflow. It seems to be closely related to your question.

Maybe it would help if you removed these lines:
        if (actuallyRead == 0)
            throw new EndOfStreamException();

Also, the loop is limited on the value of howmuch. If you don't need this value you could also use an infinite loop:
while (true)
{
    ...
}


no, removing this line and loop although don't helped
